# First item in an array is getting... replaced?

Tags: c++, arrays

New C++ learner here.

I am trying to build a struct whose member variables are 2 dynamically allocated int arrays.
The arrays are filled by std::cin.

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    int* x;
    int* y;
};

// Everything from here goes into the main()

unsigned int numArray;
std::cin >> numArray;

int* m = new int[numArray];
int* n = new int[numArray];

for(int z = 0; z < numArray; z++)
{
     std::cin >> m[z];
}

for(int z = 0; z < numArray; z++)
{
     std::cin >> n[z];
}

foo* bar = new foo;
bar->x = m;
bar->y = n;

delete[] m;
delete[] n;
```

This should have created a struct foo named `bar`, with the member variables `m` (int array) and `n` (int array).

My questions start here:

Inputs:

```
5            // length of the array
1 2 3 4 5    // for array int* x
6 7 8 9 10   // for array int* y
```

When I try to print the results with std::cout, however...

```
for(int z = 0; z < 5; z++)
{
     std::cout << (bar->x)[z] << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;

for(int z = 0; z < 5; z++)
{
     std::cout << (bar->y)[z] << " ";
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

I get this.

```
0 2 3 4 5
146890752 7 8 9 10
```

My guess is that either 1. I built the array wrong or 2. I'm accessing the array wrong (or maybe both?), but I have no idea what to do. The first item in array x always seems to be 0 while the first item in array y seems to be some random large number. What's going on?

Answer (score 3):

You deleted those arrays with `delete[] m; delete[] n;` . Then the rest of your code goes on to access deleted memory which causes undefined behaviour.

Maybe you misunderstand `bar->x = m;`. After that line, the two pointers `bar->x` and `m` both point to the same array of ints. Then you `delete[]` that array, leaving both pointers pointing to the deleted array (technically, both pointers are *indeterminate*).

If you remove those delete statements then your code should work better.

NB. If you have further questions then update your post to include your exact code, instead of describing it (e.g. `int main() {` instead of "into the main").

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.
That lead to 2 more questions:
1. Why did only the first item be weird?
2. How would I deallocate m and n later on? Is it possible to do it in another function?

Comment: @Daniel `1. Why did only the first item be weird?`  It doesn't matter if all the numbers looked "good".  You accessed memory that you shouldn't have, then all bets are off as to what to expect.

Comment: @Daniel - `2. How would I deallocate m and n later on? Is it possible to do it in another function?`  You can deallocate later in another function, but then you're taking the wrong path of writing quality C++ code.  Playing ping-pong with which function allocates and which function should deallocate is the fast way to write unmaintainable code that has memory leaks.  Instead, use a `std::vector` or other container class.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `delete[]` function, you "deallocated" the memory, but it doesn't necessarily rewrite the data immediately. Deleting just frees it up. It rewrites the first one, but it's a shallow copy, copied only by address. Though it might be a memory leak of unallocatable memory until the program terminates; that does happen sometimes.

Comment: You're answering a 1 year old question that was already correctly answered (although the answer was not accepted, this is probably abandoned by now).